# How can I rotate and translate an image from a html document using keys? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, keypress

The image moves with the arrows and rotates its gaze to where it is moving.
I have this code but when the image is at 360º, I have to restart it to 0º. But when that occurs, the image jumps in strange way

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Keys</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://icon-icons.com/icons2/281/PNG/256/Airport-icon_30354.png" id="img" style="width:100px">
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

For each key I check if I have to increase or decrease degrees to rotate the image, then check if I did not leave the limits of 0º and 360º. If so, I transform it to a correct value by adding or subtracting 360 depending on the case (for this I am removing the "transition" for a few moments to prevent the image from rotating and then I add it again) and then move the image

```
var cadena="";
var x=0;
var y=0;
var grados=0;
sumarGrados=15;

window.onload=function(e){

document.getElementById("img").style.transition="transform 0.5s linear";
document.onkeydown=function(ev){
    switch(ev.keyCode){
     case 39: cadena+="Right "; if(grados<45 || grados>225) sumarGrados=15; else if(grados>45 && grados<=225) sumarGrados=-15; else sumarGrados=0;
           if(grados+sumarGrados<0) cambio(60,0,grados+360); else if (grados+sumarGrados>=360) cambio(60,0,grados-360); 
           else{x+=60; grados+=sumarGrados; document.getElementById("img").style.transform="translate("+x+"px,"+y+"px) rotate("+grados+"deg)";} break; 

     case 40: cadena+="Down "; if(grados<135 || grados>315) sumarGrados=15; else if(grados>135 && grados<=315) sumarGrados=-15; else sumarGrados=0;
           if(grados+sumarGrados<0) cambio(0,60,grados+360); else if (grados+sumarGrados>=360) cambio(0,60,grados-360); 
           else{y+=60; grados+=sumarGrados; document.getElementById("img").style.transform="translate("+x+"px,"+y+"px) rotate("+grados+"deg)";} break;

     case 38: cadena+="Up "; if(grados<315 && grados>=135) sumarGrados=15; else if(grados>315 || grados<135) sumarGrados=-15; else sumarGrados=0;
           if(grados+sumarGrados<0) cambio(0,-60,grados+360); else if (grados+sumarGrados>=360) cambio(0,-60,grados-360); 
           else{y-=60; grados+=sumarGrados; document.getElementById("img").style.transform="translate("+x+"px,"+y+"px) rotate("+grados+"deg)";} break;

     case 37: cadena+="Down "; if(grados<225 && grados>=45) sumarGrados=15; else if(grados>225 || grados<45) sumarGrados=-15; else sumarGrados=0;
           if(grados+sumarGrados<0) cambio(-60,0,grados+360); else if (grados+sumarGrados>=360) cambio(-60,0,grados-360); 
           else{x-=60; grados+=sumarGrados; document.getElementById("img").style.transform="translate("+x+"px,"+y+"px) rotate("+grados+"deg)";} break;
    }
    console.log(grados);
};
}

function cambio(c_x,c_y,cambio){
document.getElementById("img").style.transition="transform 0.0s linear";
grados=cambio;
document.getElementById("img").style.transform="translate("+x+"px,"+y+"px) rotate("+grados+"deg)";
setTimeout('avanzar('+c_x+','+c_y+',)', 0);
}

function avanzar(c_x,c_y){
document.getElementById("img").style.transition="transform 0.5s linear";
x+=c_x; y+=c_y; grados+=sumarGrados;
document.getElementById("img").style.transform="translate("+x+"px,"+y+"px) rotate("+grados+"deg)";
}
```

What could I do to fix this?

Comment: What should the image actually _do_? If I keep pressing right, should the image continue rolling to the right? I set up a jsfiddle to experiment: https://jsfiddle.net/ay6euo07/1/

Comment: The problem is that when the airplane makes a full turn (360º) the image jumps for a moment. Try to make the image turn in a circle and you will realize what happens.

Comment: I've worked out what you want and posted an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, I finally understand what you're trying to do. You want the aeroplane image to progressively rotate towards the movement direction. Well now that I know what you want, I can work out how to achieve that. This is what I would do:

```
var cadena = "";
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var grados = 0;
sumarGrados = 15;
var normalisedGrados = 0;

onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("img").style.transition = "transform 0.5s linear";
    document.onkeydown = function(ev) {
        normalisedGrados = grados % 360;
        switch (ev.keyCode) {
            case 39:
                cadena += "Right ";
                if (normalisedGrados < 45 || normalisedGrados > 225) sumarGrados = 15;
                else if (normalisedGrados > 45 && normalisedGrados <= 225) sumarGrados = -15;
                else sumarGrados = 0;
                x += 60;
                grados += sumarGrados;
                document.getElementById("img").style.transform = "translate(" + x + "px," + y + "px) rotate(" + grados + "deg)";
                break;

            case 40:
                cadena += "Down ";
                if (normalisedGrados < 135 || normalisedGrados > 315) sumarGrados = 15;
                else if (normalisedGrados > 135 && normalisedGrados <= 315) sumarGrados = -15;
                else sumarGrados = 0;
                y += 60;
                grados += sumarGrados;
                document.getElementById("img").style.transform = "translate(" + x + "px," + y + "px) rotate(" + grados + "deg)";
                break;

            case 38:
                cadena += "Up ";
                if (normalisedGrados < 315 && normalisedGrados >= 135) sumarGrados = 15;
                else if (normalisedGrados > 315 || normalisedGrados < 135) sumarGrados = -15;
                else sumarGrados = 0;
                y -= 60;
                grados += sumarGrados;
                document.getElementById("img").style.transform = "translate(" + x + "px," + y + "px) rotate(" + grados + "deg)";
                break;

            case 37:
                cadena += "Down ";
                if (normalisedGrados < 225 && normalisedGrados >= 45) sumarGrados = 15;
                else if (normalisedGrados > 225 || normalisedGrados < 45) sumarGrados = -15;
                else sumarGrados = 0;
                x -= 60;
                grados += sumarGrados;
                document.getElementById("img").style.transform = "translate(" + x + "px," + y + "px) rotate(" + grados + "deg)";
                break;
        }
        console.log(grados);
    };
}

function cambio(c_x, c_y, cambio) {
    document.getElementById("img").style.transition = "transform 0.0s linear";
    grados = cambio;
    document.getElementById("img").style.transform = "translate(" + x + "px," + y + "px) rotate(" + grados + "deg)";
    setTimeout('avanzar(' + c_x + ',' + c_y + ',)', 0);
}

function avanzar(c_x, c_y) {
    document.getElementById("img").style.transition = "transform 0.5s linear";
    x += c_x;
    y += c_y;
    grados += sumarGrados;
    document.getElementById("img").style.transform = "translate(" + x + "px," + y + "px) rotate(" + grados + "deg)";
}
```

---

I don't know what language that is (kinda looks like Italian to me, not sure) but I worked out what the variables do. So instead of resetting `grados` to 0 or 360 whenever it goes outside those limits, I'm letting it go up or down as much as it wants. HTML handles <0 and >360 rotations just fine. I'm not sure why the image jumped when you reset it, but by letting the rotations continue increasing we don't have to care. And then to be able to still have it rotate the right way, I've added `normalisedGrados` (which, by the way, uses a simple `modulus` instead of lots of "if"s to stay in the range 0 - 360).

If you want to have a play with it, the fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/ay6euo07/3/

Comment: by the way the language is spanish xd. thank you very much, I have just one question, is not a problem leaving the variable "grados" without limit (0-360) ?, this could become a very large number if the plane takes many turns

Comment: @OmarVillanueva Ah of course it's Spanish, I should have realised. Regarding your question, no, not really. I mean technically _yes_, it would eventually reach the maximum for the number, but in practical terms that will never happen. The maximum size of a normal 32-bit integer is `2,147,483,647`. That means you would have to rotate the plane 360° in one direction approximately `5,965,232` times. That's 5.9 _million_ times. You'd be there for weeks doing that. And besides, I think when it reached its maximum the number would simply wrap around and you'd get a slight jump in the angle :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulo operator (%), like this:

```
var result = angle % 360;
```

Modulo will keep any number between 0 to 360 (assuming 360 is the limit);

Modulo simply returns the reminder from a regular division.

Wolfram alpha example: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+modulo(360)

```js
var tag = document.getElementById("demo");

var angle = 90; // degree
var limit = 360;
var result = `When angle = ${angle}, the result is ${angle % limit}`;
tag.insertAdjacentText('beforeEnd', result);

tag.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', "<br>");
angle = 360;
limit = 360;
result = `When angle = ${angle}, the result is ${angle % limit}`;
tag.insertAdjacentText('beforeEnd', result);

tag.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', "<br>");
angle = 360+180;
limit = 360;
result = `When angle = ${angle}, the result is ${angle % limit}`;
tag.insertAdjacentText('beforeEnd', result);

tag.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', "<br>");
angle = 6556443656;
limit = 360;
result = `When angle = ${angle}, the result is ${angle % limit}`;
tag.insertAdjacentText('beforeEnd', result);
tag.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', "<br>");
tag.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', "<br>");

tag.insertAdjacentText('beforeEnd', "WARNING! This can be a catch:");
tag.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', "<br>");
angle = -90;
limit = 360;
result = `When angle = ${angle}, the result is ${angle % limit}`;
tag.insertAdjacentText('beforeEnd', result);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```